# How to handle an ETIMEDOUT in node.js using http2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http2

My knowledge of node.js isn't very good and I might be missing something obvious.

I need to "crawl" a list of urls (combination of http-https, hosts and ports) for an experiment. One of those urls is not responding (it does locally, so I guess one of the middleboxes is blocking) it, which it's fine but I breaks my app as I'm not able to catch the error:

```
var http2  = require('http2');

var req = http2.raw.get('http://xxx.yyy.zzz.a:23/', function(response) {
  var content = '';
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    content += chunk;
  })

  response.on('end', function() {
    console.log(content);
    console.log('end');
  });
});

req.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

It throws the following Error (catched it with `process.on('uncaughtException', ...)`):

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.yyy.zzz.a:23]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.yyy.zzz.a',
  port: 23 }

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.yyy.zzz.a:23
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:814:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:837:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1044:14)
```

Try-catch does not work, because the function is async.
`request.on('error')` does not seem to catch this error. `setTimeout` is not implemented in this library.

I think I need to add an event into the TCP connection, but I don't know how.

I'm using node.js 0.12.7 and http2 3.2.0

Any ideas? Really appreciated

Comment: It looks like socket error events aren't propagated to the client, so without some internal changes to `http2` I don't think you'll be able to catch them (in fact, it looks like [this issue](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/issues/56) is a reminder to the developer to implement those events, but it's still open).

Comment: That was my thought, but my JavaScript knowledge is quite poor.